# Jupyter AI : There seems to be a problem with the Chat backend,

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When I install [Jupyter AI](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-ai), the `%%ai` magic command is working in the code cell, but the Chat user interface is not working and it shows the following message

> There seems to be a problem with the Chat backend, please look at the JupyterLab server logs or contact your administrator to correct this problem.

Here are the errors at the jupyterlab terminal:

```
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.711 AiExtension] Configured provider allowlist: None
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.711 AiExtension] Configured provider blocklist: None
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.711 AiExtension] Configured model allowlist: None
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.711 AiExtension] Configured model blocklist: None
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.711 AiExtension] Configured model parameters: {}
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.739 AiExtension] Registered model provider `ai21`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.739 AiExtension] Registered model provider `bedrock`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.739 AiExtension] Registered model provider `bedrock-chat`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.740 AiExtension] Registered model provider `anthropic`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.740 AiExtension] Registered model provider `anthropic-chat`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.740 AiExtension] Registered model provider `azure-chat-openai`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.740 AiExtension] Registered model provider `cohere`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.741 AiExtension] Registered model provider `gpt4all`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.741 AiExtension] Registered model provider `huggingface_hub`.
[W 2024-02-19 17:33:13.742 AiExtension] Unable to load model provider `nvidia-chat`. Please install the `langchain_nvidia_ai_endpoints` package.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.742 AiExtension] Registered model provider `openai`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.742 AiExtension] Registered model provider `openai-chat`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.742 AiExtension] Registered model provider `qianfan`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.742 AiExtension] Registered model provider `sagemaker-endpoint`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `bedrock`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `cohere`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `gpt4all`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `huggingface_hub`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `openai`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.758 AiExtension] Registered embeddings model provider `qianfan`.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.774 AiExtension] Registered providers.
[I 2024-02-19 17:33:13.774 AiExtension] Registered jupyter_ai server extension
[W 2024-02-19 17:33:13.789 ServerApp] jupyter_ai | extension failed loading with message: ValidationError(model='CohereEmbeddingsProvider', errors=[{'loc': ('__root__',), 'msg': 'Could not import cohere python package. Please install it with `pip install cohere`.', 'type': 'value_error'}])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 359, in load_extension
        extension.load_all_points(self.serverapp)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 231, in load_all_points
        return [self.load_point(point_name, serverapp) for point_name in self.extension_points]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 231, in <listcomp>
        return [self.load_point(point_name, serverapp) for point_name in self.extension_points]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 222, in load_point
        return point.load(serverapp)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 150, in load
        return loader(serverapp)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 474, in _load_jupyter_server_extension
        extension.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 435, in initialize
        self._prepare_settings()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 315, in _prepare_settings
        self.initialize_settings()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_ai\extension.py", line 238, in initialize_settings
        learn_chat_handler = LearnChatHandler(**chat_handler_kwargs)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_ai\chat_handlers\learn.py", line 66, in __init__
        self._load()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_ai\chat_handlers\learn.py", line 70, in _load
        embeddings = self.get_embedding_model()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_ai\chat_handlers\learn.py", line 295, in get_embedding_model
        return em_provider_cls(**em_provider_args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_ai_magics\embedding_providers.py", line 68, in __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs, **model_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 341, in __init__
        raise validation_error
    pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CohereEmbeddingsProvider
    __root__
      Could not import cohere python package. Please install it with `pip install cohere`. (type=value_error)
```

Then after installing the two requested packages:

```
pip install langchain_nvidia_ai_endpoints
#and
pip install cohere
```

I am still getting this error

```
[E 2024-02-19 17:46:26.012 AiExtension] Could not load vector index from disk.
```

I have another machine where I am not getting this problem. I am assuming that this might be due to firewall or some other issues. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: According to the source code, it's catching the error but not sending it to the function that actually displays an error message. So, unfortunately you'd have to troubleshoot the issue more in depth, it would seem: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyter-ai/blob/main/packages/jupyter-ai/src/index.ts#L61

Comment: The actual error gets printed to the terminal where jupyterlab was started from. Hard to help without the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter AI extension is working fine, but the Chat user-interface (UI) of the left menu is not working.  I checked the error in the terminal where jupyterlab starts. It was something related to langchain_nvidia_ai_endpoints and Cohere Python.

**Install** these two packages:

```py
pip install langchain_nvidia_ai_endpoints
```

and

```py
pip install cohere
```

**Restart computer**: The Chat UI may not work without restarting the computer.